# Using a larger blade in a table saw (circular saw)

Tags: table-saw, circular-saw, saw-blade

I am making my own table saw from a circular saw. While designing the lift cradle and box surround and my ex-circular saw which will be stripped down. So it will not have the guard.

**My saw while made for a 235mm blades, can I put a 305mm blade when I need it? 
Am I going to break my circular saw doing this?**

Comment: I stand to be corrected but I don't think it would be safe to fit a larger blade than a saw is built for, even if it will fit. The extra mass of the larger blade could exceed the strain limits of the arbor for example (both the material specs and/or its diameter), or excessively wear the bearings.

Comment: I am in the same boat as you(sort of). I might buy either the Milwaukee M18 Fuel Table Saw, Bosch 4100-10, or the Makita 2705X1. I don’t like the idea of extension cords, which along with superior appearance over the other two saws, draws me towards the Milwaukee. However, I know that in the long run, corded is cheaper since batteries have to be replaced every few years. I also dislike the smaller maximum cutting depth of the 8 1/4” Milwaukee, which is what brought me to this thread. I have heard that the plastic housing on the Makita is less durable, which is the biggest problem with the saw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably will not have an issue with the arbor but there are other issues to consider. Blade tip speed - making sure that the maximum rpm rating of the blade will not be exceeded by saw designed for a smaller blade. You other issue will be the saw will be more under powered with the larger blade. The larger diameter will require more power from the motor to provide the same cutting power at the tooth. Since you are not able to increase the power you will have less power. That's why radial arm saws were often run with the next size smaller blade to give the motor a little more mechanical advantage. Also why dado blade sets are generally smaller diameter since the kerf will be wider requiring more power.

As to damaging your saw, if you over stress the motor you are creating more heat than the motor is designed to remove and heat kills motors

Comment: I'd tend to agree with this in saying that the motor power is likely to be limiting. Also the larger the blade, the more wobble you'll get on the blade which will place stress on the arbor/bearing. Don't underestimate how much of an issue the wobble is as (though unlikely) in the worst case it could make the whole thing fail catastrophically (and dangerously).